# My if statement is not doing what I need it to do

Tags: if-statement, octave

so for my Numerical methods module we are requested solving a real world problem using Numerical methods and write a script for it through octave I am the last part of my project but it just doesn't want to do as I intend it to do? can someone perhaps help me here?

The section of code is as follows:
[Code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lRfJ.png)

```
F=1;
M=3;
input('has this met your criterion? (F/M): ')

if (F)
 printf('\n'); %Spacer
 printf('__________________________________________________ \n');%Divider
 printf('\n'); %Spacer
 printf('summation of results are as follows:');
 printf('\n'); %Spacer
 printf('___________________________________________\n');%Divider     
 printf('\n'); %Spacer
 printf(__________________________________________\n');%Divider
 printf('\n'); %Spacer
 printf('flows (m3/s)');
 QinPipe1=Q1x2=Di(1,1);
 QinPipe2=Q2x2=Di(2,1);
 QinPipe3=Q3x2=Di(3,1);
 printf('\n'); %Spacer
 printf('\n'); %Spacer
 QinPipe1=Q1x2 
 QinPipe2=Q2x2 
 QinPipe3=Q3x2

  printf("______________________________________\n");
  printf("criterion check(percentage):\n");
  printf('\n'); %Spacer
  printf('\n'); %Spacer
  RelError1=Q1e1=abs(((abs(Q1x)-abs(Q1x2))/abs((Q1x2))))*100; 
  RelError2=Q2e2=abs(((abs(Q2x)-abs(Q2x2))/abs((Q2x2))))*100;
  RelError3=Q3e3=abs(((abs(Q3x)-abs(Q3x2))/abs((Q3x2))))*100; 

  RelError1=Q1e1
  RelError2=Q2e2
  RelError3=Q3e3

else if (M)
 cramerwdntest
 end
endif
```

What I need it to do is that after it has run the previous commands up until this point once the user answers with either F or M it should either print out the summation (F) of the final results from the script run earlier and if not it should run the following m file (M) again until the user eventually answers with an (F) instead no matter what letter you enter (M or F) it runs the first part of the if statement regardless

I attempted to use the "yes_or_no" function but that seemed to not work either

Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: Please, copy-paste your code into the question, don’t post images of text. I can’t comfortably read your code this way, so can’t help you.   See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @CrisLuengo my apologies I've added the code above; I'm not sure if you need the whole code or just that section?

Answer (score 2):

What do F and M represent, and why do you set them to 1 and 3?

There's a lot to improve here, but to answer your question:

```
F=1;
M=3;
in = input('has this met your criterion? (F/M): ','s')

if in == 'F'
  ...
```

`'s'` is used to specify that you input a string (character). You must store the input in a variable. I've called it `in` but you should choose a variable name that matches its purpose in your script.

You must compare the input to the character `F`, *or* input a number instead of a string.

---

New answer:

```
in = input('Is this OK? (Y / N)', 's');
while in ~= 'Y' && in ~= 'N'
    in = input('Please answer with "Y" or "N". Is this OK?', 's');
end

if in == 'Y'
   ...
```

Comment: Hi Stewie thank you I am relatively new to this whole coding/programming thing and we were instructed to write a script, I definitely would like to improve all of this but I do not know where I could get proper guides and info for this (youtube has been my biggest help here). F and M are arbitrary at the moment as I just needed to see how the script would run but basically I would like it to represent "es and No eventually and run the correct response according to that. I attempted your solution but instead all it does is send a value back instead of running the body according to the condition

Comment: What do you get if you do: `in == 'F'` after the `in = input ... ` line? Also, end the `in = ...` line with a semi colon, then you won't get the value back, as you said. What do you get if you do `disp('Testing')` right after the `if in .. ` line?

Comment: Have a look at the new answer. Check if this works. Type Ctrl+C if you end up in an infinte loop.

Comment: after adding `disp('Testing')` nothing happens however instead of getting a value now I get an error `mx_el_eq:nonconformant arguments(op1 is 1x3, op2 is 1x2)` however after doing what you suggested in the new answer my problem seems to have been SOLVED. Thank you .Stewie